# What is python's equivalent of Matlab's ranksum?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, statistical-test

The `scipy.stats.ranksums`, `wilcoxon`, `mannwhitneyu` all give different results from Matlab's `ranksum`.

Comment: Some code to illustrate your point on where they're different would be nice.  Specifically, please attach a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends which options you are using. Check the following example:

1- MATLAB

```
rng('default') % for reproducibility
x = unifrnd(0,1,20,1);
y = unifrnd(0.25,1.25,20,1);
p = ranksum(x,y);
p =
   0.2503
```

2- Python
(to be consistent, I did not generate numbers again, but I have moved the generated numbers in MATLAB to Python script)

```
from scipy.stats import *
import numpy as np

y=np.array([0.905740699156587, 0.285711678574190, 1.09912930586878, 1.18399324775755, 0.928735154857774, 1.00774013057833, 0.993132468124916, 0.642227019534168, 0.905477890177557, 0.421186687811562, 0.956046088019609, 0.28183284637742, 0.526922984960890, 0.296171390631154, 0.347131781235848, 1.07345782832729, 0.944828622975817, 0.567099480060861, 1.20022204883835, 0.284446080502909])
x=np.array([0.814723686393179,  0.905791937075619,  0.126986816293506,  0.913375856139019,  0.632359246225410,  0.0975404049994095, 0.278498218867048,  0.546881519204984,  0.957506835434298,  0.964888535199277,  0.157613081677548,  0.970592781760616,  0.957166948242946,  0.485375648722841,  0.800280468888800,  0.141886338627215,  0.421761282626275,  0.915735525189067,  0.792207329559554,  0.959492426392903])

p = ranksums(x,y)
print p

RanksumsResult(statistic=-1.1631538287209875, pvalue=0.24476709560795806)
```

This result is with the following options:

1- for **MATLAB**:

> p = ranksum(x,y) returns the p-value of a **two-sided Wilcoxon rank sum**
>   test. ranksum tests the null hypothesis that data in x and y are
>   samples from **continuous distributions** with **equal medians**, against the
>   alternative that they are not. The test assumes that the two samples
>   are independent. x and y **can** have **different lengths**. This test is
>   equivalent to a **Mann-Whitney U-test**.

2- for **Python**:

> Compute the **Wilcoxon rank-sum** statistic for two samples. The
>   Wilcoxon rank-sum test tests the null hypothesis that two sets of
>   measurements are drawn from the **same distribution**. The alternative
>   hypothesis is that values in one sample are more likely to be larger
>   than the values in the other sample. This test should be used to
>   compare two samples from **continuous distributions**. It does not
>   handle ties between measurements in x and y.

---

**Another Example**

Here I am using the same data, with the same function of MATLAB but different options. Now you can see that the result is equal to the result from `mannwhitneyu` function in Scipy.

**MATLAB**

```
[p,h,stats] = ranksum(x,y,'alpha',0.01,'tail','left','method','exact');
p = 
    0.1267
```

**Python**

```
m = mannwhitneyu(xx, yy, use_continuity=True)
print m

MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=157.0, pvalue=0.12514839875175593)
```

Comment: How come `0.1267 != 0.12514839875...`? Different number formats?

Comment: here we have not set all the same options in both MATLAB and Python. I guess the reason for the difference can be discovered by going more into the details.

Comment: @NKN To me, the first one is similar, so when you mentioned MATLAB's tests the median, I assume Python's too?